# How to make only one package,not all packages?

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My OS is ubuntu 12.10 64bit and using ROS groovy.

I only want to compile output_h_w package,but it will compile other packages in catkin workspace together. Output_h_w is my own package.
I have some package with problems in my catkin workspace. Therefore, I don't want them to be compiled together, only compile Output_h_w package and skip others.

```
My Commond:catkin_make --pkg output_h_w
```

I get the same result when using catkin_make.

When I use catkin_make --pkg,I get the following message:

```
lian@lian:~/code/ros_groovy$ catkin_make --pkg output_h_w
Base path: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy
Source space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/src
Build space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build
Devel space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel
Install space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - output_h_w
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_generated
-- ~~  - sam_move_head_down
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'output_h_w'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(output_h_w)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'pr2_moveit_generated'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(pr2_moveit_generated)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sam_move_head_down'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sam_move_head_down)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "pr2_controllers_msgs" with any of the following names:

    pr2_controllers_msgsConfig.cmake
    pr2_controllers_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pr2_controllers_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "pr2_controllers_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "pr2_controllers_msgs" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sam_move_head_down/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

When I use catkin_make,I get the following message:

```
lian@lian:~/code/ros_groovy$ catkin_make 
Base path: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy
Source space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/src
Build space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build
Devel space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel
Install space: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/lian/code/ros_groovy/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - output_h_w
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_generated
-- ~~  - sam_move_head_down
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'output_h_w'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(output_h_w)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'pr2_moveit_generated'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(pr2_moveit_generated)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sam_move_head_down'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sam_move_head_down)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "pr2_controllers_msgs" with any of the following names:

    pr2_controllers_msgsConfig.cmake
    pr2_controllers_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pr2_controllers_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "pr2_controllers_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "pr2_controllers_msgs" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sam_move_head_down/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
lian@lian:~/code/ros_groovy$
```

The result are the same.
How to solve it ? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67155/how-to-make-only-one-package,not-all-packages-?/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-11**:
Also, please stop opening duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With `catkin_make` all of the packages in a workspace are built with a single `cmake` and `make` invocation. The `--pkg` option will run `make` on the package specified, but it must run `cmake` on all of the packages, that is why you are getting the same error even with the `--pkg` option. If you don't want particular packages (packages with known problems) to be processed then you can delete them from the workspace or add a CATKIN_IGNORE file in the package's directory.

If you want a little more control over which packages get built when, then you can also try `catkin_make_isolated` which is capable of running `cmake` and `make` for only one package at a time.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-12**:
Also, consider making a separate workspace for your own packages that overlays the system versions.